# Prevent view from being dragging to side menu

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have Side Menu controller in which you can access all of controllers, side controller. For some reason, when i drag one of my view (which is actually typical view controller) touching it from left to right, it drags and show Side Menu controller. Please take a look:

[image]

How to prevent this behaviour? Is there any UIView methods that can help?

I tried:

```
 if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]){
    [self.navigationController.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer];
    }
```

But its not work, i guess that is because this is not navigation controller issue.

Comment: Are you using some 3rd party library for that side menu view controller? Or do you implement it natively?

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov its not 3rd party library but written by another dev.

Comment: Hard to say. 
Could you please describe your structure? Provide more code..

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov i found that problem is in 3rd library - MDTabBar. But i didnt find how to fix it.

Comment: Provide more details, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for slide menu implementation I generally use the `framework(pod)`

```
pod 'SWRevealViewController', '~> 2.3'
```

it can have all methods `gesture on/off`,`tap on/off`.
I hope you will like this!!